# Seems that methods of maven repository can not be called from end-product

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

I am setting up a Craftbukkit Server with the editor IntelliJ and the programming language Java. For that I use firebase-admin. I want use it trough maven and everything works. But when I build the .jar and then let it run it returns following error in the console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at raycroud.mckaff_server_manager.ServerManager.onEnable(ServerManager.java:26) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:254) ~[craftbukkit-1.13.2.jar:git-Bukkit-a4c555b]
```

I am sitting at this problem for many days and tried many different solutions, but nothing worked.

Here you can see my project structure:
[image]

And here my Artifacts Settings under File->Project Structure->Artifacts:
[image]

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>company.lol_server_manager</groupId>
        <artifactId>server_manager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
                <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Actual the Craftbukkit plugin gets disabled but I normally I expect that he works and I don't know why he can find methods or other elements from maven libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons.
It would help if you provide your run/debug configuration.
You could try the following:

- Activate [Include in project build].

Let me know if it helps.

[image: Include in project build]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in my case it fixed the problem to setup a new intelji project